# What is the u vector in the expression for the weights of the min variance portfolio

Tags: portfolio-management, minimum-variance

I was working on my finical math homework where I need to find the minimum variance portfolio.  I need to use the following matrix expression.

[image]

Nowhere in the class notes does the instructor say what the u vector in the above expression is.  At first I thought it was the expected returns of each portfolios (however that would be the m vector).  I reverse engineered the result of an example and it appears the u is just a vector of all ones.  Not sure if this is a finance thing or a matrix algebra thing.  Does u stand for unit vector as in a vector of all ones?  What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes u is the unit vector of all ones